# How to install gems from RubyForge?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rubyforge

I am trying to install [ruby-mp3info](http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=62&release_id=34916) as a gem on my computer.
Running sudo gem install ruby-mp3info seems to work OK.
In my environment.rb file, I added `config.gem "ruby-mp3info"`.
When I try to run the server, it fails, claiming I have some missing gems
Following the error message's advice:

```
Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.
```

I run the command, which simply returns my local path. Running the server again - I get the same error message.

Could someone explain what I am doing wrong? How does one go about installing gems from RubyForge - or in general?

How does the gem command know where to find the necessary files - they are not all stored on my computer. Does it have hardcoded urls built into it?

Comment: try running `rake gems:install --debug`, maybe it will provide a useful stacktrace

Comment: no cigar. it just return me to the command line- no output whatsoever (not even the path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what did the trick.
In my environment.rb file, I had the following:

```
config.gem "ruby-mp3info"
```

Playing around with the options, I found that I had to specify the `lib` attribute:

```
config.gem "ruby-mp3info", :lib => "mp3info"
```

This solved the problem.

Comment: the irony, by the way, is that after I went through all of that I realized I had no use for the library... I am consoled by the fact that this post may save someone the two hours I spent looking for a solution...

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar problem on servers when running Phusion Passenger (mod_rails).  Problem being I forget to update the Passenger gem repository like this:

```
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090421/bin/gem install whatever
```

instead of simply this:

```
gem install whatever
```

It would be a useful utility for someone to write, keeping the 2 gem repos in sync.